# How to default to Complete Install in Wix?

Tags: c#-4.0, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have Wix 3.5, WixUI_Mondo dialogs and only one Feature to install. The Installer still shows the "Choose Setup Type" page - even though there is only one feature.

How do I hide or skip this page and do a complete install by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Mondo isn't the right dialog set for you.  Have you checked out [WixUI_InstallDir](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_installdir.htm)?

Comment: I don't want to give an option to change install location. All I really want is the EULA and a check box to open application after install.

Comment: Sounds like you should look at WixUI_Minimal then.